# Configure IntelliJ to use Subversion

Tags: intellij-idea

How to configure IntelliJ IDEA to use Subversion?

Answer (score 33):

Depending on what you enabled when you installed IDEA you might also need to enable the "Subversion Integration" in Settings -> Plugins.

Comment: This is useful. My IDEA suddenly crashed and after restart, all the thing relating to SVN disappeared (no context menu, no thing in the preferences ...) your comment suggested me to reset the plugin and it worked again.

Comment: Thanks! For me Subversion Integration was unticked aswell. Couldnt understand what had happend.

Comment: Thanks! After having checked out the new project from Subversion, Subversion integration suddenly disappeared from VCS tools. Somehow, the option became disabled.

Comment: This saves me hours. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 11):

For version 10:

- Top Menu -> Version Control ->
  Checkout from Version Control ->
  Subversion
- Click the plus button in
  front of "Repositories"
- Add your SVN
  server URL.
- Click in the newly
  created repository (enter credentials
  if needed).
- Browse to your project
  root and click the Checkout button.
- Follow the wizard.

To import something into subversion, do the same thing using the Import Into Version Control menu.

Cheers

Answer (score 6):

If you want to configure Subversion with Intellij 9.0.X, I take configure intelliJ to use the system default subversion configuration directory in your desktop/laptop.

All I did was in Settings -> Version Control select Subversion from the drop down. IntelliJ will do the rest to point to your default Subversion directory (be in Win 7, XP for example).

[image]

Then like how @Anthony suggested you can add your main subversion URL there or by clicking on Version Control -> Browser Subversion Repository where you can add the URL.

Comment: Useful information. I think IntelliJ picked the svn command from my PATH variable or something like. Setting this option enables a lot of Subversion specific features at Top Menu > Version Control.

Answer (score 2):

Faced that question times ago. As Anthony said, I enabled VCS and tried to import, but got "not a working copy" errors. Also excluded "out" folders come into VCS.

So the solution is to select "Share on subversion" from "VCS - Import" menu. There you can also add "trunk" catalog to Google Code SVN if you had to clear it before.

Then you got your project files in changes list. Commit it.